# How we extract inserted script with revisions-objecct of MS word VBA for lots of docx-file

Tags: vba, ms-word, revision

In case that I have lots of docx documents which are recorded change track, how do we extract inserted sentence from these docx documents ?

By searching, I understood I should use **Revisions collection**.

However, I couldn't do it.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/135435-post6.html

Comment: i think it's a VBA for EXCE not for WORD

Comment: Both sets of code are for extracting revisions from Word documents. It's the output that gets sent to Excel.